# Splitting up "Stamps" in quarter, tens, fives, twos and ones

Tags: python, algorithm

I recently solved a question to split the stamps (An amount in terms of money) with as less coins as possible. The function takes the amount and returns the split of the amount with least coins possible

```
def stamps(num):
    quarter = num / 25 
    ten = (num % 25) / 10
    five = (num % 10) / 5
    two = (num % 5) / 2
    one = (num % 2) 
    return quarter, ten, five, two, one
```

All the coins comes fine but there is some error coming up with stamps(68). It excludes one(1) in the last. Please can some explain where am I going wrong with a reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's unclear what exactly you are trying to do?  what are stamps?  can you give some sample input and output (where it is working correctly or incorrectly)

Comment: does it work for stamp(6)?

Comment: @GarrettR - Pls check the edits

Comment: @stefan - no. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This breaks on 6 too. The reason is that `num % 2` is not the correct residual amount after adding 2s, because we changed the parity by using a 5. A corrected code is

```
def stamps(num):
    quarter, num = divmod(num, 25)
    ten, num = divmod(num, 10)
    five, num = divmod(num, 5)
    two, num = divmod(num, 2)
    one = num  # or one, num = divmod(num, 1); you could extract a loop
    return quarter, ten, five, two, one
```

Comment: Pls can you explain the parity. your one = num part works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @deep 6, the original amount, is even. 1, the amount remaining after we used a 5, is odd.

Comment: this greedy algorithm should work excellent ... let it be noted that this will break for some denominations of stamps (not in the problem statement)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `one` equal to the remainder of `num/2`.

68 is an even number. There is no remainder of `68/2`, therefore, your variable `one` will be 0.